# Create monthly time series with arbitrary start dates

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Using `pandas` it is easy to create a monthly series of dates.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.date_range('2012-04-23', '2013-01-23', freq='BM')

DatetimeIndex(['2012-04-30', '2012-05-31', '2012-06-29', '2012-07-31',
               '2012-08-31', '2012-09-28', '2012-10-31', '2012-11-30',
               '2012-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```

Notice that the dates in the `DatetimeIndex` are month ends.  I know that it should be considering I chose `freq='BM'` but I don't believe I had a choice that would have accomplished my goal.

I'm often in need for producing a monthly series of dates starting from the last business day going back in time every month.

I'd like to see this instead:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2012-04-23', '2012-05-23', '2012-06-23', '2012-07-23',
               '2012-08-23', '2012-09-23', '2012-10-23', '2012-11-23',
               '2012-12-23'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

or another more complicated example might be to get months from '2012-01-30' to '2012-04-30'.  I'd expect to see:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-30', '2012-02-29', '2012-03-30', '2012-04-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: I don't understand.  What you just asked doesn't appear to be what you'd like to see, i.e. the top DatetimeIndex *is* the last business day in the month going back in time.

Comment: @Alexander This is a result of my not knowing what to put as the `freq` argument.  I did not want to produce daily which I believe is the default.

Comment: So today is May 6th (already?!?...).  March 6th is a Sunday.  What would you like to see?  March 4th (Friday)?

Comment: @Alexander Yes.  But I did not specify that in the question.  I did not want to complicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day, BDay
pd.date_range(start = '2012-01-01', periods = 6, freq = 'MS') + Day(22) + BDay(0)
Out[12]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-23', '2012-02-23', '2012-03-23', '2012-04-23',
               '2012-05-23', '2012-06-25'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

`Day(22)` adds an offset of 22 days and `BDay` is responsible for business day offset (`BDay(0)` takes the nearest business day).

It's a bit more difficult with dates starting at 30th. So I had to write a function for this. (For clarity of code it doesn't allow a custom `freq` parameter.)

```
def my_business_date_range(day, **kwargs):
    assert(isinstance(day, int) & (day > 0) & (day < 32))
    rng0 = pd.date_range(freq = 'MS', **kwargs)
    rng1 = rng0 + pd.tseries.offsets.Day(day-1) + pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(0)
    # Correcting overflows:
    overflow_idx, = np.nonzero(rng0.month != rng1.month)
    if overflow_idx.size > 0:
        # rng1 is not mutable
        tmp = rng1.tolist()        
        bme = pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthEnd(-1)
        for i in overflow_idx:
            tmp[i] = bme(rng1[i])
        rng1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(tmp)
    return rng1

my_business_date_range(30, start= '2012-01-01', periods = 6)
Out[13]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-30', '2012-02-29', '2012-03-30', '2012-04-30',
               '2012-05-30', '2012-06-29'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Pandas has also an experimental [`CustomBusinessMonth` and the like](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days-experimental) but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: This is great. A lot of good insight and references to interesting functions. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on your question, but believe this is a move in the right direction.

```
start = '2012-04-23'
end = '2013-01-23'

>>> pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.datetime(ts.year, ts.month, int(end.split("-")[-1])) 
                      for ts in pd.date_range(start, end, freq='BM')])

DatetimeIndex(['2012-04-23', '2012-05-23', '2012-06-23', '2012-07-23', '2012-08-23', '2012-09-23', '2012-10-23', '2012-11-23', '2012-12-23'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Although not optimized for speed, I believe the following function will return the correct values per your requirements.

```
def foo(date, periods, forward=True):
    if isinstance(date, str):
        date = pd.Timestamp(date).date()
    dates = [date + relativedelta(date, months=n * (1 if forward else -1)) for n in range(1, periods +1)]
    result = []
    print dates
    for date in dates:
        month = date.month
        iso_day = date.isoweekday()
        if iso_day == 6:
            date += dt.timedelta(days=2 if forward else -1)
        elif iso_day == 7:
            date += dt.timedelta(days=1 if forward else -2)
        if date.month != month:
            # Gone into next/preceding month.  Roll back/forward.
            date -= dt.timedelta(days=3 if forward else -3)
        result.append(date)
    return result
```

Comment: This will definitely work for the specific set of dates I used in this example.  I already have a robust if convoluted solution.  I wanted to solicit other opinions so I might have a cleaner answer.  I'll follow up with additional comments in my question.

Comment: 'BM' does not appear to be a valid option for Periods.  What if today was 2016-6-01 (Weds).  2016-05-01 is a Sunday, so would you want to see 2016-04-28 (Friday)?  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets

Comment: That is such a good question.  I'd have to choose 2016-05-02.

Comment: My solution involves rolling back one month at a time and making decisions considering several factors like, is it a weekend, if so roll backwards unless that dips into the prior month (your example) otherwise roll forward.  Was the original date a month end, business month end or beginning and should end-ness or beginning-ness be preserved.

Comment: Do you prefer to take the ending date and work backwards per those rules, or a start date and work forwards?

Comment: I specify that as an option.  I imagine a solution in one direction could be generalized in the other.