# Bug or feature? Generating a pd.date_range from July 15 for monthly frequency produces time indices at end of month

Tags: pandas, time-series

Here's my code:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2016 Jul 15 10:15', periods = 10, freq = 'M')
```

This produces the following DateTimeIndex:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-31 10:15:00', '2016-08-31 10:15:00',
               '2016-09-30 10:15:00', '2016-10-31 10:15:00',
               '2016-11-30 10:15:00', '2016-12-31 10:15:00',
               '2017-01-31 10:15:00', '2017-02-28 10:15:00',
               '2017-03-31 10:15:00', '2017-04-30 10:15:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Why is the hour I selected respected but not the date? Is this a bug or am I missing something in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) that would explain this?

Comment: It's a feature. For the start of the month, use `freq='MS'`. [Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

Comment: @ptrj But what if I want to go monthly from an arbitrary date, as above?

Comment: @ptrj Actually seems like 'MS' starts at my arbitrary date, but I don't see how I would do the start of the month in that case?

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37094414/5717589) might be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't seem consistent to me. I understand freq='M' is going to give me month ends. But why is it going leave the time alone?  That said. why should I expect it to return beginning of the day of the last month?  Maybe, respecting the time is best practice.